# Find two prime factors of a number so that the multiplication of factors give the original number

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I have a number say N, I need to divide this number into p and q so that when I multiply p and q I would get original number back. Also, p and q should be two prime numbers.

Google search suggest to find the factor of the number.[link](https://medium.com/asecuritysite-when-bob-met-alice/cracking-rsa-a-challenge-generator-2b64c4edb3e7). See the example and it's subsection, factor.

Now, I can understand if the number N itself is a prime number then I can find it's two factors as prime number. Like if N is 23, I can get two factor 1 and 23 and they are prime. Otherwise, if the number N is a squared number like 49 or 25 I can get there factors, and the factors are prime numbers.

Like if N is 49 and it's factors are 7 and 7 both are prime numbers.

Now, N not necessarily a prime number. It could be a non prime number like if the N = 2,542, Factors are = 2 x 31 x 41, where 31 and 41 are prime numbers but 31*41 = 1,271 which is not equal to 2542.

So, the question arise how could I divide a number into two prime numbers so that there multiplication should be the original number

Comment: This is - unsurprisingly - only possible if $N$ is the product of two prime numbers.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  $1$ is not a prime.  Most numbers are not the product of two primes.  For those that are...well, factoring large numbers is really hard.

Comment: Perhaps you would benefit from reading about [the fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I can not follow you. Why N always be a product of two prime numbers?

Comment: @Joe I cannot understand " every integer greater than 1 can be represented uniquely as a product of prime numbers". How? They give us an example of 1200 but I can not found unique prime p and q so, that p*q will return 1200. The factor 2,3,5 they are primes but 2^4 is not prime and so on.

Comment: uniquely as the product of $m$ primes, where $m\ge 1$. So $1200=2*2*2*2*3*5*5$, which is the product of 7 primes (not distinct). So, as @HagenvonEitzen commented, you can only find two primes that multiply to give $n$ if $n$ is in fact the product of two primes, meaning that its prime factorization contains only two primes (not necessarily distinct). Otherwise, there is no way to find two primes that multiply to give $n$.

Comment: @joe For 1200,  there are 7 prime numbers but it is also not possible to make two prime numbers(p, q) from these 7 prime numbers so that there product p*q would return 1200. So, in RSA cracker how could they divide N into the product of only 2 prime numbers?

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable about encryption, but my assumption is that they multiply two primes to get an $N$, not start with an $N$ which hopefully is the product of two primes, both because the latter is likely to fail, and because it would be horribly inefficient. In fact, the whole point is for the encryptor not to have to do that factorization.

Comment: @Joe, Your assumption is correct when you need to take user input for two prime numbers, p and q and then generated a public key and encrypted msg and private key. Then use this private key to decrypt or find the plain text from the encrypted msg. However, in the RSA cracker product you have encrypted msg, public key and N(modulus) using those you need to generate the private key and plain text.

Comment: Maybe you should change your question to be about that problem, and use the "cryptography" tag.

Comment: See Wikipedia article on [Prime omega function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function). $n$ is the product of exactly two primes iff $\Omega(n)=2$

Answer (score 1):

In the RSA scheme, you use two prime numbers p, q and their product N = p*q. The RSA scheme depends heavily on the fact that given a large enough N, it is practically impossible to find p and q. So you don’t start with N and try to factor it - if you could, then I could crack your encryption.

Instead you start with two primes p and q and calculate N from them.